# Who is this engineer?

Tags: support, 500-server-error

So whilst <s>SE is going completely mental</s> an error occurred I came across this non-feline engineer working on the [SE server](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309105/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz).

[image]

I was wondering who this is? Is he an employee of SE? Is he a ♦ user? But more importantly - why is he not a cat?

Comment: You *sure* he's not a cat? He sure seems to be playing with that mouse...

Comment: Clearly, Nick Craver is a cat in a human-shaped mech suit. I'm sure most/all employees of Stack Overflow Inc are.

Comment: @Kendra We get standard-issue human suits because it's hard to work without opposable thumbs. Now if only I could figure out if I want my office door open or closed...

Comment: Just fit a flap. Problem solved.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311135/447356

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's me when I first started at Stack Overflow. I didn't yet know what a mouse was.

Comment: I see from your hand that the SO Fight Club rumours are true!

Comment: I know that Stack Exchange doesn't emphasize exact tech matches when hiring people (e.g. you don't need C# experience specifically), but never knew this took it this far...

Comment: And you had one single computer, shared by all developers... awesome! :D

Comment: @Carpetsmoker rather than hiring for a particular "technology" or "basic understanding of how to use a computer", we hire for pure untapped talent. This allows us mold any new hire into our ideal developer, sysadmin, or barista, based on whichever is most needed at the time.

Comment: If I recall, you used to be an avid PC gamer before joining Stack Overflow... you must have really known your keyboard shortcuts well :D